# Почему редиректит с главной страницы в админ-панель?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Есть мультиязычный сайт на WordPress: рус, англ, итал. Проблема в том, что при переходе по ссылке [www.realprestigeproperties.com/it](http://www.realprestigeproperties.com/it) , редиректит на https://realprestigeproperties.com/wp-admin/ . Хотя 301 редирект (переадресация) через .htaccess настраивали. Подскажите, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Исправляй вопрос - расскажи как сделана мультиязычность и покажи что вы там понастраивали в хтацессе (и зачем?)